How to resize table rows based on its content?
I am trying to write a logic where table rows are resized based on its content.
I am currently using @tanstack/react-table and @adsk/alloy-react-table for the table creation.
Current table implementation looks something like this ->
  return (
    <table
      style={{
        border: `1px solid ${Theme.colors.charcoal200}`,
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <thead style={{ position: "sticky" }}>
        {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
          <TableHeaderGroup
            key={headerGroup.id}
            style={{ height: "30px" }}
            {...getTableHeaderGroupProps(headerGroup)}
          >
            {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
              <TableHeader
                style={{
                  ...headerStyles,
                }}
                key={header.id}
                {...getTableHeaderProps(header)}
              />
            ))}
          </TableHeaderGroup>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody
        ref={tableBodyRef}
        style={{ height: "200px", overflow: "auto", display: "block" }}
      >
        {paddingTop > 0 && (
          <tr>
            <td style={{ height: `${paddingTop}px` }} />
          </tr>
        )}
        {virtualRows.map(virtualRow => {
          const row = rows[virtualRow.index] as Row<DemoAttributes>;

          return (
            <TableRow key={row.id} {...getTableRowProps(row)}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                <TableCell
                  key={cell.id}
                  style={cellStyles} // this is empty object
                  {...getTableCellProps(cell)}
                />
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
        {paddingBottom > 0 && (
          <tr>
            <td style={{ height: `${paddingBottom}px` }} />
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );

I have tried adding white-space: 'normal' style to the content div, hoping if content is bigger than the cell/row then it wraps to the next line.
It works for two lines but if content goes to the third line then it starts spilling over other rows
how can I make so that content stays within the cell and the cell expands if the content is large?
Adding a screenshot here of what it looks like currently

